# How to use jquery properties in a jquery plugin EasyDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use a easydate jquery plugin for finding the date difference between two dates.

I am able to come up with this code and it works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>jQuery EasyDate - Human-readable JavaScript date formatting</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Demo</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><abbr class="easydate">Mon, 05 Jan 2012 12:12:10 </abbr></li>
        <li><abbr class="easydate">Sun, 04 Aug 2013 02:42:10 </abbr></li>
        <li><abbr class="easydate">Sat, 01 June 2015 08:42:10 </abbr></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://easydate.parshap.com/files/jquery.easydate-0.2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".easydate").easydate({'format_future':'false'});
    </script>
</body>
```

And it seems that the Options has to be setup using this syntax

```
$(".easydate").easydate([options]);
```

Some of the available options are

```
Property        Description
format_future   Determines if EasyDate should format dates that are in the future.
Default: true
```

Now, how do I set up these options in the above syntax and try?

I tried, for eg:

```
    $(".easydate").easydate({'format_future':'false'});
```

and used a future date like below

```
    <li><abbr class="easydate">Sat, 01 June 2015 08:42:10 </abbr></li>
```

But still the date is shown as " in 2 years" but that shouldn't be because I set the option "format_future" as false.

Bear with me if my question is too naive because I just started with jquery now.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I took this plugin from [here](http://easydate.parshap.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes:

```
$(".easydate").easydate({format_future:false});
```

I have created a fiddle for this don't know whether this what you are expecting

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96W3y/)

Comment: The key is "Remove the single qoutes"! Thanks. Exactly what I expected! Lesson learnt : Never ever put single quotes to a boolean value... And boolean false is not 'false' or "false" ...